# Extracting string after x number of backlashes in swift

Tags: swift

I can't find any way to extract a certain string value from another string in SwiftUi.

It is the following link:
"http://media.site.com/videos/3070/0003C305B74F77.mp4"

How would you go about extracting the numbers 0003C305B74F77?

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to treat it as an URL. That's what it is. All you need it to get its last path component after deleting its path extension.

```
let link = "http://media.site.com/videos/3070/0003C305B74F77.mp4"
if let url = URL(string: link) {
    let lastPathComponent = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    print(lastPathComponent)  // "0003C305B74F77"
}
```

Comment: I agree with Leo. (voted.) The tools in foundation for parsing URLs are quite good, and that's safer and easier than trying to roll your own string parsing.