# Get a part of a string that comes before .mp3 but is not always the same link

Tags: swift

I want to get only the ID that comes before the .mp3 but after several attempts I can't do it, the link is not always the same length

String examples:

```
"https://urlexample.com/EXAMPLE_STRING/media/example/audio/20227/07/1657142074431_15789.mp3"
"https://urlexample.com/media/THIS_TEXT_IS_1657130179082_24048.mp3"
```

The result should be:

```
"https://urlexample.com/audio/1657130179082_24048"
"https://urlexample.com/audio/THIS_TEXT_IS_1657130179082_24048"
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: Hint: consider https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1407365-pathcomponents

Comment: `URL(string: yourString)?.deletingPathExtension()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531595/2303865

Comment: @Jessy I have tried to obtain the string by specific ranges but as the link comes with different lengths, it did not work for me. I have considered that it was not necessary to put it in the question, because perhaps seeing it in a simpler way, someone would know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a URL with your string then get the id

### Code :

```
let string = "https://urlexample.com/EXAMPLE_STRING/media/example/audio/20227/07/1657142074431_15789.mp3"

guard let url = URL(string: string) else {
    // not a url string
    return
}
  
// file name with extension  
let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
print(fileName) // 1657142074431_15789.mp3

// file id 
let fileId = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
print(fileId) // 1657142074431_15789
```